# Javascript inserttext with newline

Tags: javascript, php

I cannot get below code working:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right" style="margin-bottom:5px;margin-right:1px;" onclick="insertText('replytext', '[quote=<?php echo user::getUsername($message['poster']);?> date=<?php echo $message['post_date'];?>]<?php echo $message['message'];?>[/quote]');">
                            <i class="fa fa-reply" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>


<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="replytext" id="replytext"
                      style="width:100%;background-color:black;color:white;resize: none;"></textarea>



 <script>
        function insertText(elemID, replytext)
        {
            var elem = document.getElementById(elemID);
            elem.innerHTML += replytext;
        }
    </script>
```

When replytext contains new lines it will not fill the textarea with this value as it should do. Anyone have an idea how to fix this? It's related to replying a message with /n or br  within it.

I've tested it. When there are no /n or br it is working.

Comment: To add dynamic content, go for `append()` in Jquery.

Comment: Hi @YashParekh, '$("#replytext").append(replytext);' doesnt work as well. I receive 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token'

Comment: See this for your reference :- http://jsfiddle.net/nQErc/

Comment: Hi @YashParekh, intried the code but cant get it working. Im probably doing something wrong. $('#replytext').append($(replytext).text());  do you know the correct code?

Comment: Just tell me what you are getting in `elemID, replytext` inside the function.....

Comment: Hi @YashParekh, I receive Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: Think i know what the problem is. It seems onClick is not accepting a new line. I deleted the new line, and now it is working. So i'll add a bb code for new line, and will preg replace the new line. I will try it now, brb!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the question author)*.

```
str_replace(PHP_EOL, '[br]',($_POST['replytext']))
```

This did the job. `onClick` function doesn't allow `<br />` or any kind of new line.

Answer (score 1):

The new line won't show in the view because you should convert the "new line" (`\n`) into html line break, which is `<br />`.

Try this:

```
function insertText(elemID, replytext)
{
    replytext = replytext.replace(/\r?\n/g, "<br />");
    var elem = document.getElementById(elemID);
    elem.innerHTML += replytext;
}
```

The `replace(/\r?\n/g, "<br />")` statement will replace the "new line" into HTML line break (`<br />`).

Comment: Hi samAlvin, thanks for your help. I tried your code but it is not working. The textarea did not get filled. It seems it is not working when a new line is detected

Comment: @RonnieOosting could you somehow log this value from `<?php echo $message['message'];?>`, e.g. put this statement inside a `console.log` method?

Comment: @sameAlvin i receive 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token'

Comment: str_replace(PHP_EOL, '[br]',($_POST['replytext'])), did the job.